# Is there a way of passing an Integer value from mapper class to all reducers

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to pass this Integer value like a=100 to all reducers. Then in the reduce function, I can use this value. Is there a way to do this? I don't want to put this value to  pair like <"a", 100> since it will go to a specific reducer that I don't know and in this case, not all reducers will receive this value.

The value is needed by every reducer.

Comment: Please explain what you are actually trying to accomplish.  This value needs to be part of every `reduce()` call?  In addition to, or separate from, other data?

Comment: yes, I want to use this value in every reducer. That means I need to access this value in reduce() function no matter which key I was assigned in the current reducer.

Comment: When is the value known?  Is it statically available before the job starts?  is it computed dynamically by some other process?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass this through the JobConf object. Assign the JobConf which you get in configure to a local instance and set the value. Should be available in  configure() of reducer.